# IOS 10,xcode 8,swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using xcode 8 ,ios 10 for ios development.I have issue in slider menu.I have used slider menu with user profile photo,but when I upload or change the profile or logout active user and relogin different user then SWReveal does not refresh, it holds previous user profile.

**Any help would be appreciated!!**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell:MenuTableCell=tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MenuTableCell

    if(cell.menu.text=="Logout"){

        let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
        UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain!)
        print("session end")

        let mainstorybord:UIStoryboard=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let des=mainstorybord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
        let frontview=UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:des)

        revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(frontview, animated:true)
    }

}
```

Comment: where u cleare the memory of  image or userdefault vale

Comment: make your userDictionary nil when you logout